# How to do "USERNAME" Encryption in Django website database.?

Tags: python, django

I made a simple student information system using Django framework. I already encrypt the password in Django database admin/login using Pbkdf2 library and it display the password encryption in database which uses sha256 encryption algorithm. i tried to apply the same library to encrypt the username as well, When i check the log it display the encryption but does not display in actual database. How can i encrypt the username any other way so the username will not be display in django database.

Comment: It is not common practice to hash usernames like passwords. It would require knowing the username to view or edit it.

Comment: I appreciated your reply Klaus. But is there a way I can hash the Username if it's possible and display it on the database? I want to give it try for single username if i already knew the username would it be possible?

Comment: What do you indent to use the datavase for?

Comment: I am using database to store student information.